# My Richfaces 4.0 project won't work with ui:composition tag

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

My Richfaces 4.0 project won't work with ui:composition tag.

Here is a xhtml-file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
 xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

  <h:head>
   <title>RichFaces</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
  <ui:composition>
   <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectsBean.currentType}"
            valueChangeListener="#{selectsBean.valueChanged}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectsBean.firstList}" />
            <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second" execute="@this" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="second" layout="block">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectsBean.currentType}"
                rendered="#{not empty selectsBean.currentType}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectsBean.secondList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
  </ui:composition>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

If I delete ui:composition tag, page works correctly, but with this tag skin does not load and valueChangeListener don't work. Where may be the problem?

**UPD:**
Thomas pointed out a mistake, but page still not work. Now xhtml file contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
   <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectsBean.currentType}"
            valueChangeListener="#{selectsBean.valueChanged}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectsBean.firstList}" />
            <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second" execute="@this" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="second" layout="block">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectsBean.currentType}"
                rendered="#{not empty selectsBean.currentType}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectsBean.secondList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
  </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the facelets doc: `Any content outside of the UI Composition tag will be ignored by the Facelets view handler.`

And from the official JSF2 doc: `JSF disregards everything outside of the composition...`

AFAIK the `<ui:composition>` tag has to be the top level element in your file.

Comment: Thanks for information, but after I change it, the problem persists.

Comment: How did you change that? Note that you might add the xml namespaces to the tag, i.e. `<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" ...>`.

Comment: Do you also have a page that includes your file using `<ui:include ... />`? Note that `<ui:composition ...>` is generally used for templates that are included somewhere and not for standalone pages. Thus you'd have to use a wrapping page as well.